# Create a new variable from the minimum in R

Tags: r

The data contains four fields: `id, x1, x2, and x3`.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
x1 <- c(2,4,5,3,6,4,3,6,7,7)
x2 <- c(0,1,2,6,7,6,0,8,2,2)
x3 <- c(5,3,4,5,8,3,4,2,5,6)

DF <- data.frame(id, x1,x2,x3)
```

Before I ask the question, let me create a new field (`minX`) which is the min of (`x1,x2,x3`)

```
DF$minX <- pmin(DF$x1, DF$x2, DF$x3)
```

I need to create a new field, `y`, that is defined as follows

```
if min(x1,x2,x3) = x1, then y = "x1"
if min(x1,x2,x3) = x2, then y = "x2"
if min(x1,x2,x3) = x3, then y = "x3"
```

Note: we assume no ties.

Comment: See, also, `?max.col` for similar problems; `names(DF[-1])[max.col(-DF[-1], "first")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `data.table` solution:

```
# create variables
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
x1 <- c(2,4,5,3,6,4,3,6,7,7)
x2 <- c(0,1,2,6,7,6,0,8,2,2)
x3 <- c(5,3,4,5,8,3,4,2,5,6)
DF <- data.frame(id, x1,x2,x3)

# load package and set data table, calculating min
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, minx := apply(.SD, 1, min), .SDcols=c("x1", "x2", "x3")]

# Create variable with name of minimum
DF[, y := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) names(x)[which.min(x)]), .SDcols = c("x1", "x2", "x3")]

# call result
DF
##     id x1 x2 x3 minx  y
 1:  1  2  0  5    0 x2
 2:  2  4  1  3    1 x2
 3:  3  5  2  4    2 x2
 4:  4  3  6  5    3 x1
 5:  5  6  7  8    6 x1
 6:  6  4  6  3    3 x3
 7:  7  3  0  4    0 x2
 8:  8  6  8  2    2 x3
 9:  9  7  2  5    2 x2
10: 10  7  2  6    2 x2
```

The last step can be called directly, without the need to calculate `minx`.
Please notice that `data.table` is particularily fast in large data sets.

**######## EDIT TO ADD: DPLYR METHOD #########**

For completeness, this would be a `dplyr` method to produce the same (final) result. This solution is credited to @eipi10 in a question I started out of this problem [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196854/r-dplyr-get-name-of-which-min-rowwise):

```
DF %>% mutate(y = apply(.[,2:4], 1, function(x) names(x)[which.min(x)]))
```

This solution takes about the same time as the `data.table` one provided in the original answer, when applyed to a 1e6 rows data frame (about 17 secs in my sony laptop).

Comment: an alternative for the apply function: `DF[, y := names(.SD)[which.min(.SD)], by = 1:nrow(DF), .SDcols = 2:4]`

Answer (score 4):

As a simply solution, do:

```
VARS <- colnames(DF)[-1]
y <- VARS[apply(DF[, -1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = which.min)]
DF$y <- y
```

The function `which.min` returns the index of the minimum. If the minimum is not unique it returns the first one. Since you guarantee that there is no tie, this is not an issue here.

Finally, you should be familiar with `apply`, right? `MARGIN = 1` means applying function `FUN` row-wise, while `MARGIN = 2` means applying `FUN` column-wise. This is an useful function to avoid the need for a `for` loop when dealing with matrix. Since your data frame only contains numerical/integer values, it is like a matrix hence we can use `apply`.

Comment: You need to get rid of the ID column though

Comment: Why creating all those intermediate variables and not just `DF$y <- colnames(DF)[-1][apply(DF[,-1], 1, which.min)]` ?

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus need a `which.pmin` and your data.table solution suggest that is provided in that package.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `pmin` and `max.col`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, c("minx", "y") := list(do.call(pmin, .SD), 
             names(.SD)[max.col(-1*.SD)]), .SDcols= x1:x3]
DF
#    id x1 x2 x3 minx  y
# 1:  1  2  0  5    0 x2
# 2:  2  4  1  3    1 x2
# 3:  3  5  2  4    2 x2
# 4:  4  3  6  5    3 x1
3 5:  5  6  7  8    6 x1
# 6:  6  4  6  3    3 x3
# 7:  7  3  0  4    0 x2
# 8:  8  6  8  2    2 x3
# 9:  9  7  2  5    2 x2
#10: 10  7  2  6    2 x2
```